# Encoding a message to a point of curve y^2=x^3+7 and Bitcoin Core

Tags: dsa, cryptocurrency, encoding

Where should I look at in [Bitcoin Core source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/secp256k1/src) to figure out how the signature process transform a message in a curve point?

To sign a transaction (message) in the Bitcoin system, you need to encode the message to a point of the curve $y^2=x^3+7$. I read this [Koblitz's paper](http://math.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH508/KoblitzEmbedding.pdf). There are three encoding schemes. I read [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/koblitz-encoding-a-message-to-a-point-what-is-the-associated-auxiliary-base-pa) too.

If I look at in Bitcoin Core source code I can't see any of these encoding schemes, it seems to me that message $M$ is directly encoded in a point ($ \rightarrow \operatorname{hash}(M) $) without check; obviously that is not possible, there is roughly a 50% chance that a random 256 bit string doesn't correspond to a point of the curve. I can't find out how/if the ECDSA library checks if $\operatorname{hash}(M)$ is on the curve or not and especially what it does if the $\operatorname{hash}(M)$ is not on the curve.

What encoding scheme does Bitcoin-ECDSA implement and where is it in the source code?

Comment: Since this is more about Bitcoin than cryptography, you might get better anwers on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

In ECDSA, the message is never encoded as a point in the elliptic curve. Signing in ECDSA loosely works like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
k &= \text{random}(0, n) \\
(x, \_) &= k \cdot G \\
r &= x \bmod n \\
s &= k^{-1}(H(m) + r \alpha) \bmod n
\end{align*}
$$

$r$ and $s$ are the signature, and as you can see $H(m)$ is only ever used as an element of the integers modulo $n$, the order of the generator point $G$ (and $\alpha$ is the private key). Therefore, $H(m)$ is never treated as a point, and thus never needs to be encoded into one.

Comment: You're right! I thought that "r" was a curve point, but it isn't! Thank you very much!